# Why does nothing pass Firebase validation? Why are no error messages returned?

Tags: javascript, database, validation, firebase, angularfire

I'm using the following security rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "chat": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": true,
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['author', 'message'])"
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm using `$add` to save objects to my `chat` $firebaseArray in this format:

```
{message: "hello there", author: {emailAddress: "javier@test.com"}}
```

But it always fails if `.validate` is defined. It saves correctly if `.validate` is not defined. So I tried extending $firebaseArray like this:

```
    var myFarr = $firebaseArray.$extend({
        $$error: (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })

    this.messages = myFarr( $scope.firebaseData.$ref().child('chat') )

    this.sendEmail = (function(_this) {
      return function(email) {

        _this.messages.$loaded().then(function(data) {
          data.$add(email);
        })["catch"](function(err) {
          console.error(err);
        });

      };
    })(this);
```

But the `$$error` method never seems to fire.

Why isn't my valid data validating and how can I get appropriate error messages?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `$add()` operation that fails.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a level for the specific chat message in your rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "chat": {
      "$chatid": {    
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['author', 'message'])"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your rules were applying the validation to all-chat-messages-combined, while you want to apply them to each individual chat message.

Comment: This information is also in the [official docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html). I read the docs several times, but this info didn't register with me because I am dumb.